# Why are non-const vector<bool> elements const?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, constants, extraction-operator

When I iterate over a `vector<bool>`, I find that the elements, dereferenced through the iterator, are recognized as if they were const. Why is that? Change either the container or the element type, such as `list<bool>` or `vector<short>`, and the elements are non-const. This code shows what I'm talking about:

```
typedef bool T;
#define C vector
istringstream &operator>>(istringstream &iss, T &v)
{
    cout << "non-const" << endl;
    return iss;
}

istringstream &operator>>(istringstream &iss, const T &v)
{
    cout << "const" << endl;
    return iss;
}

istringstream &operator>>(istringstream &iss, C<T> &c)
{
    for (C<T>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
    {
        iss >> *it;
    }
    return iss;
}

int main()
{
    C<T> c(1);
    istringstream iss("1");
    iss >> c;
}
```

For `vector<bool>`, this program prints "const" to the console. Change the typedef and manifest constant at the top to anything but those two combinations, and it prints "non-const." Also, if I replace the line, `iss >> *it`, with `T v; iss >> v; *it = v;`, it works as expected--all combinations print "non-const."

I see the same behavior with GCC 4.1.2 C++98 (via codepad.org) and VS2015 C++14+ (?).

Comment: Short answer: `std::vector<bool>` is special. You can find a reference on it to see exactly what's different.

Comment: Yes, I, uh, just noticed that. I'm writing some fancy templates, and I'd rather not specialize for bool.

Comment: Read some interesting facts on `vector<bool>` here : https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Comment: The short version: `vector<bool>` isn't a container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the name, `vector<bool>` contains no `bool`s, and dereferencing its iterator doesn't give you a `bool&`. Instead, it gives you an object of type `vector<bool>::reference`, which tries to imitate the behavior of `bool&` as much as it can.

There's no way to convert a `vector<bool>::reference` to a `bool&`, so the non-const overload doesn't work. `vector<bool>::reference` can, however, be converted to a `bool`, which can then bind to the `const bool&`.

Answer (score 5):

To save memory, `vector<bool>` isn't an actual array of `bool`. A bool value need only a bit to be stored, but the smallest size possible is 1byte = 8bits. Therefore, by not using the trivial implementation, you can have an 8 times more efficient storage (as far as memory is concerned) then what a simple array of bool would provide.

However, the consequence is that an element of a `vector<bool>` is not a bool but a `vector<bool>::reference` which is almost but not quite the same as a `bool&`. Most operations are here, but some aren't (like `|=` for exemple)

Still you can either convert it to a `bool`, or initialize a new `const bool` object with it ... and do whatever you what with this new object

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<bool>` is a specialization of `std::vector` that acts a space-efficent dynamic bitset. The iterators returned from `begin()` and `end()` actually point to an objects of a proxy class type representing booleans.

The references returned from dereferencing the iterators are prvalues of class type, not actual booleans. It is converted to a prvalue of `bool` type so that is why the overload taking a reference to const is perferred (rvalues can bind to references to const).

Comment: Thanks, chris, T.C., and 0x499602D2. That explains it. Taking chris's advice, I found a [good article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm).